# M/M/1/K Queue vs M/D/1/K Queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, intuition, queueing-theory

I simulate both M/M/1/K and M/D/1/K, with same arrival rate and same queue size K. I get the result that rejection probability of M/D/1/K is lower than M/M/1/K, but I could not quite see why constant service time lowers the rejection probability. May someone gives me the intuition behind this? Also, in general, what influence does constant service time or arrival time have in the queue?

Comment: The single-server formula for an $M/G/1$ queue gives intuition, since the delay in the queue (before starting service) is, for $\lambda < 1/E[X]$:  $$\overline{W}_q =\frac{\lambda E[X^2]}{2(1-\rho)} = \frac{\lambda[E[X]^2+ Var(X)]}{2(1-\rho)}$$ where $\rho = \lambda E[X]$, and so we see that service time variance $Var(X)$ increases delay. So for a given $\lambda$ and a given mean service time $E[X]$ (and hence a given $\rho$), the smallest delay is when the service time variance is zero, which corresponds to fixed length jobs, that is, $X=E[X]$ with probability 1.